# Is there an environmentally-friendly dishwasher soap that will remove baked-on egg?

Tags: home, water, cleaning

Previously, we used Cascade Platinum Dishwasher pods, which were over 90% successful at removing baked on egg from baking dishes. Unfortunately, that product has a [scary list of ingredients](https://smartlabel.pg.com/00037000977261.html).

We've been trying various environmentally-friendly alternatives, but so far none of them are as effective as Cascade Platinum.

**Is anywhere aware of a dishwasher soap product or recipe that can remove baked-on food?**

Comment: Have you tried softening the the baked on food by soaking it for about an hour prior to washing the dish? Instead of using a lot water to soak the item, place a saturated towel, or similar, over the affected region.